# Folders for subdomain-specific files beside Laravel's folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'd like to make a Laravel app, where the subdomains' folders are beside the Laravel project folder. If a file (eg. a controller file) is not found in the current subdomain's folder, then it's loaded from the main project folder.

So my folder tree would look like this:

- Laravel project (all Laravel files)

  - app
  - Http

    - Controllers
    - ...
  - ...
  - ...
- Subdomain1 (only subdomain specific files)

  - app
  - Http

    - Controllers
    - ...
  - ...
  - ...

Can I have Laravel behave like this?

Thank You for your help!

Comment: How about you try it and let us know?

Comment: you want to check controller file in route ?

Comment: I've tried googling for answer, but noone seems to have exactly this problem, that's why I asked it.
I imagine something like if Laravel needs a file, it tries to load it from the subdomain dir, and if not found, it falls back to the main Laravel dir.